# I am trying to use allure reporter in protractor but it is not working

Tags: angularjs, protractor, allure

When I only add one line

```
var reporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
```

It starts giving an error, saying

> ERROR - failed loading configuration file config/protractorConf.js

`protractorConf.js` is the file where I added that line.

Please guide me where I am doing mistake.

I have Node version 4.1.1 and I also upgraded to 8 but still had same problem.

Comment: Show your protractorConf.js and package.json

Comment: it was working fine but when I just added .. require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
it started giving that error.

Comment: Open a cmd window and switch to your project folder, then type node to enter into node interpreter, and execute `var reporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter')` interpreter. To check this package can be loaded successfully or not.   Or you can delete the entire folder `node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter` and reinstall it.